# Sending expo notification per user and broadcast notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I am trying to make a notification per user, not per device.

ex: If I logged into two devices, I want to send a notification to both devices.

Something else that I want is to send a broadcast notification for all users using the expo server. Is that possible?

Which is better - using expo server or Firebase push notification?

Answer (score 1):

You have to save both: user ID and ExpoNotificationToken (device token) in your database for each device.

```
|userUuid | ExpoNotificationToken |
----------------------------------
| abc     | abc-device1-token     |
| abc     | abc-device2-token     |
-----------------------------------
```

Then, if you want to notify this particular user, send notifications to all ExpoNotificationTokens, connected with this user ID in a loop.

Expo Broadcaster is much easier to use, You have a simple REST interface (POST endpoint), which is responsible for sending notifications to given tokens. Expo also handles all credentials on their side. On the other hand, you are dependent on third-party services. IMO, if you use Expo in your project, it's natural to use their broadcaster as well, they provide libraries and support for this solution.

Comment: what if in same device login another user? or two user more and total 3 user with same token?